# Modifiying SparkFun Uh-Oh Batt. Indicator - TL431 Regulator Diode Based

Tags: led, diodes, low-battery

I'm trying to modify a simple SparkFun Uh-Oh Battery Level Indicator - KIT - 11087 https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11087

It can handle a maximum voltage of 12 or so volts, above that I believe it would burn out. I need to use it with a battery pack that has a nominal voltage of 19.2 V (made up of 16 NiMh cells). It has to act as a low battery indicator in the 17 or 18 V range.

I'm far from being an expert in electronics, so I've been trying to understand the basics of this simple circuit, but I can't clearly see how I could modify it.

Here is the schematic for the batt. level ind.:

http://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Kits/UhOh-v11_corrected.pdf

Please ask for clarification if needed!

BTW, if I can sort this out, I need to make about 100 of these higher voltage versions.

Comment: "It can handle a maximum voltage of 12 or so volts, above that I believe it would burn out." Where did you hear this?

Comment: According to the datasheet, the TL431 can work up to 36V, so you should be ok with 19.2V

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, you are helping me clarify things. I did a bit of testing and at 10 V 20 mA is going through the LED. At 15 V it is about 36 mA! If I understand this correctly it will burn out the LED? V to the LED varies from 3.3 to 3.6 V or so.

Comment: Replace the resistor by one of 750 ohms and you'll be fine. Using Ohm's Law, \$R_1 = \dfrac{V_{cc} - V_{LED} } {I} = \dfrac{18V - 3V}{0.020A} = 750 \Omega\$.

Comment: Humm... not luck so far. I've swapped out the original 330Ω resistor for a 750Ω one and now the LED stays on all the time!

Comment: Also I should add that the TL431 is extremely hot and is heating up the entire PCB! This is with the power supply at 15 V. The low batt. ind. is now consuming 120 mA which is way above the 25 mA it consumed with the 330Ω resistor. So this doesn't work on two levels. Worth a try but I guess this is more complex than I can grasp.